# How to create complex types with entity framework?(include or partial view)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been working on entityfreamwork with Mvc for a long time.

When creating complex types, I use my entityframework include method or do I break the model by sending id to partial views?

Im using partial view

```
<div class="sidebar-item product-info">
            <h4>İlan Durumu</h4>
            <hr class="line-separator">
            <!-- INFORMATION LAYOUT -->
            <div class="information-layout">
                <!-- INFORMATION LAYOUT ITEM -->
                <div class="information-layout-item">
                    <p class="text-header">Başlangıç Fiyatı:</p>
                    <p>@string.Format("{0:N0}", Model.MaxPrice) ₺</p>
                </div>
                <!-- /INFORMATION LAYOUT ITEM -->
                @Html.Action("AuctionBestOffer", "Offer", new { auction = Model.Id })
                <!-- INFORMATION LAYOUT ITEM -->
                <div class="information-layout-item">
                    <p class="text-header">Favorilere Ekle:</p>
                    @Html.Action("UserHasFavoriteAuctionDetail", "FavoriteAuction", new { auction = Model.Id, title = Model.Title })
                </div>
                <!-- /INFORMATION LAYOUT ITEM -->
            </div>
            <!-- INFORMATION LAYOUT -->
        </div>
```

Auction ComplexModel

```
public class GetAuctionDetailModel : ViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public int CityId { get; set; }

    public AuctionBaseCategoryType BaseCategory { get; set; }

    public AuctionBaseType AuctionBaseType { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public decimal MaxPrice { get; set; }

    public string Count { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Offer ComplexPartialModel

```
public class GetOfferForAuctionDetail : ViewModel
{
    public OfferStatus OfferStatus { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Offer controller

```
public ActionResult AuctionBestOffer(int auction)
    {
        var response = _offerService.GetBestOffer(auction);
        if (response.IsCompleted)
            return PartialView(response.Data);
        return null;
    }
```

Auction Controller

```
public ActionResult AuctionDetail(string title,int id)
    {
        var response = _auctionService.AuctionDetail(id);
        if(response.IsCompleted)
        return View(response.Data);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new {notificationError = response.Message});
    }
```

on the other way OfferAuctionMixModel

```
public class GetAuctionDetailModel : ViewModel
{
public int UserId { get; set; }

public int CategoryId { get; set; }

public int CityId { get; set; }

public AuctionBaseCategoryType BaseCategory { get; set; }

public AuctionBaseType AuctionBaseType { get; set; }

public string Title { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }

public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

public decimal MaxPrice { get; set; }

public string Count { get; set; }

public bool IsActive { get; set; }

public List<GetOfferForAuctionDetail> OfferModels { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public List<GetAuctionDetailModel> GetModel(int id)
    {
        using (VerBiTeklifContext context = new VerBiTeklifContext())
        {
           var item =context.Auction.Where(s => s.Id == id).Include(s => 
           s.Offer);
          //mapping operations...
        }
    }
```

I can do the same process using include method. Which one should I use?

Good work for everyone...

Comment: please add your model and controller to question too

Comment: Im so sorry. I edited